# What content-type is set in response when we pass an array to produces condition in Spring MVC (@ResponseBody)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For example if we have -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = {
        RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}, produces = {
        MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
```

**Edit**
What will be the response content-type?

For two different `accept` headers -

1. text/html, application/xhtml+xml, * /*
2. */ *

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "pass an array to produces condition" here??

Comment: It means I am passing array to `produces` as in `produces = {
        MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on configured content negotiation and type selected by request. For example if request has header Accept: application/json or client requested resource with suffix ".json" he will receive json response. http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the parameter is wrong. It does filter the incoming request by types the client accepts. As an example: If you are just producing "text/html" but the client only accepts "application/json" your mapped function in the controller denies the request.

Side note: Which type to produce can be configured with [content negotiation](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)

Comment: It does effect the response content-type. [Producible Media Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces)

Comment: Nope the doc only says that it ensures the correct response type for the end user. You can put in there whatever you want but it only blocks the request.

Comment: Thanks. How should I handle situations depending on the request `accept` header? For example `text\html` in accept-header should set `text/html` in response `content-type`.

Comment: Use the content negotiation. Your ViewResolver (e.g. Jackson/JSP) will take care.